# Find the number of partitions of $n$ in which each part is at least $3$

Tags: combinatorics, integer-partitions

Find the number of partitions of $n$ in which each part is at least $3$

Let $h_n$ be the number of partition of $n$ in which each part is at least $3$. I'm pretty sure that the generating function would be
$$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}h_nx^n=\frac{1}{(1-x^3)(1-x^4)(1-x^5)\cdots}$$
I'm not sure how to use this to find the desired number

Comment: https://oeis.org/A008483

Comment: Are you sure about how to use the generating function for unrestricted partitions to find the number of unrestricted partitions? If you can't do that, you can't expect to do it for your partitions which are restricted to those with each part at least three. And if you can do it for unrestricted partitions, what stops you from using the same method for your restricted partitions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In addition to the generating function argument Gerry is hinting at, there's an inclusion/exclusion argument if you're content with a formula for your $h(n)$ in terms of $p(n)$, the number of partitions of $n$.  Namely, $$h(n) = p(n) - p(n-1) - p(n-2) + p(n-3).$$
Among the $p(n)$ partitions of $n$, there are $p(n-1)$ of them with at least one part 1.  And among the partitions of $n$, there are $p(n-2)$ of them with at least one part 2.  We want to remove those, but we have overcounted since there can be partitions of $n$ with at least one 1 and at least one 2; there are exactly $p(n-3)$ of these since removing the necessary 1 and 2 leaves a partition of $n-3$.

Comment: Interestingly, that formula is given at the oeis page to which RobPratt linked.

Comment: @GerryMyerson Not surprising.  I like when these things have combinatorial explanations, although the generating function would be straightforward here.